# bonjour mDNSresponder for Android

Tags: android-ndk, bonjour, mdns

I went through the below links http://mirror.yongbok.net/linux/android/repository/external/mdnsresponder/ to get the apple mdns responder cross compiled on the android ndk . but I cloud not get the build it . 
got the below error .

make: Circular obj/local/armeabi/libmdnssd.so <- obj/local/armeabi/libmdnssd.so dependency dropped.
SharedLibrary  : libmdnssd.so
arm-linux-androideabi-g++: ./obj/local/armeabi/libmdnssd.so: No such file or directory

If any one has cross built    it for android pls help .

Comment: 23 questions and you accepted no answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think here you are looking for jmdns.listbysubtypes . You can try this for browsing subtypes

map mp =  jmdns.listbysubtypes(_smartplace._tcp.local)

you can try this , once you get it then u can play with map object

Answer (score 1):

There's an Android-friendly implementation of Bonjour called [JmDNS](http://jmdns.sourceforge.net/). Feel free to download and integrate on the Java side.

Implementation is not exactly straightforward. There's the wrinkle with explicitly enabling multicasts over WiFi (look it up), and the JAR that's hosted on SourceForge is no good. But StackOverflow is full of guidance and samples.

Comment: I tried the jmdns but could't browse the subtypes I've registered my service with subtype using mdnsreponder(applebonjour) on my linux pc
.I'm trying to browse the service using jmdns (here I've jmdns.jar) on my Galaxy phone .I registered service using the below command
$dns-sd -R CAM _smartplace._tcp.,_wcam local 80  
When I browse with out subtype in the service type list of jmdns I get the proper response.i.e
ServiceInfo[] https = jmdns.list("_smartplace._tcp.local.");  Hence  but using avahi I am able to browse for the subtypes , hence I go with cross building mdnsresponder for andorid

Comment: Once you get a `serviceAdded()` callback, call `requestServiceInfo()`. Then you'll get `serviceResolved()` which will list service details.

Comment: Hi, I am able do the service browse but not able to do the subtypes . may jmdns is incompitable with apple bonjour . because in bonjour we can browse the service by subtypes but in jmdns we gave to use the service type only .